# Cleanup tmp dirs when hitting CTRL-C from perl -d debug session

Tags: perl, signal-handling

For the temp directory I need in my script, I go with:

```
my $work_dir = File::Temp->newdir(TEMPLATE => "/tmp/work.$$.XXXX" ) or die "Cannot create tempdir directory $!";
```

My hope with [newdir()](http://search.cpan.org/~dagolden/File-Temp-0.2304/lib/File/Temp.pm#newdir) is to get the promise of:

**By default the directory is deleted when the object goes out of scope.**

Only to learn that if I hit CTRL-C, $work_dir will **NOT** be removed.

So I added signals:

```
use sigtrap qw(handler signal_handler normal-signals);
```

and then I simply use (File::Path 'remove_tree');

```
sub signal_handler
{
    remove_tree $work_dir;
}
```

This helps if I hit CTRL-C while my script runs...

However, it does NOT clean up while using the debugger, **if** I CTRL-C out of the debugger! If I quit out cleanly (with the q command) then it works/cleans fine, only if I CTRL-C out of the debug session, that's when $work_dir is not being removed.

Is it possible, in any way, to have the signal handler being called automatically even within a perl debug session ?

(or any other "proper" ways how to use/install signal handlers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your signal handler isn't doing what you think it does, because passing an object to `remove_tree` doesn't work:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use File::Path qw(remove_tree);
use File::Temp;

my $tmpdir = File::Temp->newdir(CLEANUP => 0);
remove_tree $tmpdir;

say "$tmpdir still exists" if -d $tmpdir;
```

Outputs:

```
/tmp/lTfotn79RD still exists
```

The call to `remove_tree` in your signal handler *seems* to work when run outside of the debugger, but it's actually not doing anything. (You can prove this to yourself by commenting out the call to `remove_tree` and re-running your script.) So why does the directory get removed?

If a signal handler doesn't `exit` or `die`, execution continues wherever it left off before the signal was caught. In your case, after the signal handler finishes, the program simply runs to completion. When the program terminates, any objects that are still in scope are cleaned up by calling their `DESTROY` methods. `File::Temp->newdir` returns a `File::Temp::Dir` object; this object's `DESTROY` method is what actually removes the directory from the filesystem (it uses `rmtree` under the hood).

This doesn't work when you interrupt the debugger; I'm not familiar with the debugger's internals, but I'm guessing it keeps references to objects so that `DESTROY` isn't called, even when you step off the end of the program. If you <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> again at this point, the object is never cleaned up, and neither is the temporary directory.

One way I found to work around this is to explicitly `undef` the object returned by `File::Temp->newdir` in your signal handler:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use File::Temp;

use sigtrap qw(handler cleanup normal-signals);

my $tmpdir = File::Temp->newdir;

sub cleanup {
    my ($sig) = @_;
    say "Caught signal SIG$sig";
    undef $tmpdir;
    exit 0;
}
```

This causes the `DESTROY` method to be called *before* the program exits, so you're not relying on the debugger to clean up. This seems like kind of a hack, though; why not just quit the debugger gracefully with `q`?

Note that you could also pass the stringified version of `$tmpdir` to `remove_tree` like this:

```
remove_tree "$tmpdir";
```

But I wouldn't recommend this, since the documentation [strongly cautions](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Temp.html#WARNING) against relying on file names:

> For maximum security, endeavour always to avoid ever looking at, touching, or even imputing the existence of the filename. You do not know that that filename is connected to the same file as the handle you have, and attempts to check this can only trigger more race conditions. It's far more secure to use the filehandle alone and dispense with the filename altogether.

Comment: nice workaround with the undef ... and, yes, normally I try to be civil and exit with `q`. However, in some cases when I forgot to put a proper `b`, I had to interrupt ... and sometimes with successive CTRL-C _stuff happens_ and I was hoping/looking how to get around that! Thanks

Comment: You could always add your breakpoint and then restart with `R`. But I know what you mean, I Ctrl-C out of the debugger too, sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use an END block.  The any clean exit from the program, especially a 'quit' from the debugger will trigger the END block an, in my case, delete all my test data.

So put your clean up code in and END block have have you sig handler call exit() instead of remove_tree.

```
 END {
   remove_tree $work_dir;
 }

 sub signal_handler
 {
     exit();
 }
```

Comment: This doesn't work if you Ctrl-C to exit the debugger itself, which I assume is what the OP is asking about.

Comment: Yup! TSBN got it right! I'd love to understand in some more depth why, and how to get it to work? I guess for that one needs to be _familiar with the debugger's internals_